# Запретить сохранять в БД строки, содержащие потенциально опасный js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, валидация, node.js

Привет
Пишу тут на node.js + socket.io небольшой чат, и возник вопрос:
 -как правильно валидировать сообщения (например регуляркой), чтобы запретить пользователю отправлять сообщения теоретически содержащие javascript код? Не подкинете пример такой регулярки?

Comment: Лучшей защитой будет экранирование сообщения, чтобы даже если в нем есть JS- он был отображен как текст. Все остальное- потенциальная дыра в безопасности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну валидировать его не обязательно, достаточно или не устанавливать значение пришедшее с бекенда через `.innerHTML` ну или фильтровать его например так при отправке:

```js
var unsaveBtn = document.getElementById('unsaveBtn');
var saveBtn = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
var message = document.getElementById('message');
var result = document.getElementById('result');

function esc(html) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.textContent = html;
  return el.innerHTML;
}

unsaveBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result.innerHTML = message.value;
});

saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result.innerHTML = esc(message.value);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="message">
  <b>Hello!</b>
  <script>
    alert();
  </script>
</textarea>
<br/>

<input type="button" id="unsaveBtn" value="Опасно отправить" />
<input type="button" id="saveBtn" value="Отправить безопасно" />

<div id="result"></div>
```